# Proof of Lebesgue Density Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If E is a Borel set in $\Bbb R^n$, the density $D_E (x)$ of $E$ at $x$ is defined as

$$D_E(x) = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{m(E \cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}$$

Show that $D_E(x) = 1$ for almost everywhere $x \in E$ and $D_E(x) = 0$ for almost everywhere $x \in E^C$.

I am not sure what to do to prove this statement.  As far as I can tell, this is the Lebesgue Density Theorem, but I can only find proofs of this in the one-dimensional case (which is by far the easiest case).

Comment: This follows from the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) by considering the characteristic function of $E$. This is a standard result found in measure theory books. There is also a proof on Wikipedia.

Comment: Ah.  I see it now.  I started to try that, but got stumped.  I focused too much on trying to prove it with epsilons and such.  Not useful.  Thanks.